# UIView management with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC and I just ran into a problem, I mean some memory leaks so I have a question: What are the main things I have to do with the subviews I add to my view?

For example, should I `-removeFromSuperview` these views in `-viewDidUnload` if I added them in `-viewDidLoad`? Or maybe I should do something in the `-dealloc` method?

Comment: check if viewDidUnload is calling, because it is deprecated in iOS6, so it wont be calling.

Comment: If you are using ARC then you not worry about releasing memory of UI because it maintain by it self :)

Comment: if you are facing leaks problem with ARC project , assign nil to any controller after using it in another one

Comment: Are you using 'UIImage' or 'UIImageView'?

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier what's the purpose of that question?

Comment: If using `imageNamed` for loading images, they typically stay in memory until the app quits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean some memory leaks

Use instruments to detect where the memory leaks are and solve them.

> What are the main things I have to do with the subviews I add to my
>   view?

Normally the `UIViewController` will manage the views for you, but I cannot tell you anything else without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to removeFromSuperView,if there are some UI you won't use,just make it to nil,ARC will do the memory manage for you

Answer (score 0):

Superview will retain subview and superview will release it automatically. No need to worry.
But if you have any strong pointers (e.g. in view controller) looking at your subview, you should nil them to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Actually he doesn't need to nil them. If it's a strong property ARC will release and nil them for you.